# pig storage script failing

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, dump

I am running a pig script , it is running fine but it fails when I am trying to store the output in file. **dump works fine.** 
Could someone please let me know the reason or at lease guide me to how to troubleshoot.

```
pig -useHCatalog;
a = load 'geolocation_part' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = filter a by truckid == 'A1';
Dump b;
store b INTO '/user/admin/pig/scritps/geolocation_20160401';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should have the correct script like below

```
pig -useHCatalog;
a = load 'geolocation_part' using org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = filter a by truckid == 'A1';
store b INTO '/user/admin/pig/scritps/geolocation_20160401';
```

DUMP is used to view the data relation. It displays the data and we can confirm that the operation are getting correct data.

Never use DUMP in the script.

**Do not use DUMP as it will disable multi-query execution and is likely to slow down execution. (If you have included DUMP statements in your scripts for debugging purposes, you should remove them.)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have added the the dump just to show that it is working but store is not working. It found the actual error message about the permission and i could resolve it.